# How to pass values from shell execution to Jenkins variables?

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

I am working on a Jenkins DSL script where I need to pass some values from shell execution to groovy variables. Following is the code -

```
sh  '''   stopPrimary="$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${primaryInstanceId} 2>&1)"
            stopSecondary="$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${secondaryInstanceId} 2>&1)"
            stopTest="$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-323223232323 2>&1)"
      ''' 
//Testing if both instances are stopped else throwing an error
if ( stopTest.contains("An error occurred") || stopSecondary.contains("An error occurred") )  {
       error("One or more actions failed - ${stopPrimary} ${stopSecondary}")
} else {
       echo "Storage Servers stopped now - Proceeding with Terraform apply"
}
```

I need the values of variables in shell execution (stopPrimary,stopSecondary,stopTest) to be used in next if-else block of code. However, this doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins scripted pipeline: Unable to print variables inside shell and set variable values in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449204/jenkins-scripted-pipeline-unable-to-print-variables-inside-shell-and-set-variab). See the 2nd part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450130/7571258) -> Return structured data.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sh` directive is starting a child process, running `bash`. Your child process inherits all the environment variables of the parent process, and may create some of its own variables. Once your child process dies, all the variables — both inherited and created — die with it.

The way to deal with it is one of the two:

1. If you only need to understand if your command succeeded or failed, you may rely on error status instead of error message. Usually, linux commands return 0 if they ran successfully, and non-0 otherwise. Jenkins fails the pipeline on any non-0 command. So, the following *may* be enough:

```
sh "aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${primaryInstanceId}"
```

If this command returns non-0 status, the pipeline will fail. You can wrap it with `try { ... } catch () { ... }` to raise your own error.

2. If you need to use the output later in the pipeline, you have to either get it from the output (e.g. by running `sh script: "...", returnStdout: true`, or you may want to write it into a file and real that file later.