# Not getting variable value in jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, variables, jenkins-pipeline, jq

I am using the below `Jenkinsfile`. It is printing the value of `upload_id` when it is executing with the `jq` command, but when printing the value it is showing `null`.

Please help me to fix this variable issue.

```
sh label: '', script: 'upload_id=$(cat output_file.json | jq -r \'.upload_id\')'
sh "echo \"$upload_id\""**
```

Output :

> [Pipeline] sh
>   cat output_file.json
>   jq -r .upload_id
>   upload_id=8f304c6d-804b-440a-xxxx**
>   [Pipeline] sh
>   echo upload_id : null
>   upload_id : null
>   [Pipeline] }

Comment: Its showing upload id with jq parameter but while printing value its showing null
Output :
[Pipeline] sh
+ cat output_file.json
+ jq -r .upload_id
**+ upload_id=8f304c6d-804b-440a-8db3-xxxx**
[Pipeline] sh
**+ echo upload_id : null**
**upload_id : null**
[Pipeline] }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins scripted pipeline: Unable to print variables inside shell and set variable values in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449204/jenkins-scripted-pipeline-unable-to-print-variables-inside-shell-and-set-variab)

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can I use above two commands as per your suggestions. 1. sh label: '', script: 'upload_id=$(cat output_file.json | jq -r \'.upload_id\')' 2. sh "echo \"$upload_id\""**

Comment: In your case, the section "Return a single string" of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450130/7571258) would apply.

Comment: Here, I am using pipeline script. Writing this code like pipeline{ stages { stage() { steps{  sh label: '', script: 'upload_id=$(cat output_file.json | jq -r \'.upload_id\')' sh "echo \"$upload_id\"}}}. Can you please suggest me how should I use here to get value of user_id.  Output :

[Pipeline] sh cat output_file.json jq -r .upload_id upload_id=8f304c6d-804b-440a-xxxx** [Pipeline] sh echo upload_id : null upload_id : null
[Pipeline] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to go with [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60707404/7571258), because it is the cleanest way.

Anyway, there are situations where there is no other choice than to use the shell, so here is the shell way:

```
script {
    def upload_id = sh label: '', 
                       script: 'echo $(cat output_file.json | jq -r \'.upload_id\')', 
                       returnStdout: true
    upload_id = upload_id.trim()  // remove extraneous whitespace
    sh "echo \"$upload_id\""
}
```

I've already linked to a more [detailed answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450130/7571258) but you were probably not getting it to work, because you are using a declarative pipeline. In declarative pipeline, you have to use a `script` block to be able to store return values of steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. Now its working fine. But there is one issue. Its taking one extra line in the value. Please help to fix the issue.                                                                                                                       + echo Upload id : 6b84fd50-8036-447c-84fa-xxxxxxxx

Upload id : 6b84fd50-8036-447c-xxxxxxxxxxxx

[Pipeline] sh

Comment: @Raghunath I've added a trim() to remove the extra line.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this intrinsically in Jenkins Pipeline to avoid all of the issues with subprocess execution. First, read in and parse the JSON file:

```
upload_info = readJSON(file: 'output_file.json')
```

Then, you can access the returned values in the assigned `upload_info` Map normally:

```
upload_id = upload_info['upload_id']
```

Comment: Getting this error - sh: "Syntax error: "(" unexpected". I am using below command under steps{ sh "upload_info = readJSON(file: 'output_file.json')"
                sh "upload_id = upload_info['upload_id']"
                echo "$upload_id" }

Comment: @RaghunathDhara I am not sure what you wrote there, but that is not what is in my answer. Please use what is in my answer.

Comment: Here, I am using pipeline script. Writing this code like pipeline{ stages { stage() { steps{ sh label: '', script: 'upload_id=$(cat output_file.json | jq -r \'.upload_id\')'  sh "echo \"$upload_id\"}}}. Can you please suggest me how should I use here to get value of user_id. Output : [Pipeline] sh cat output_file.json jq -r .upload_id upload_id=8f304c6d-804b-440a-xxxx** [Pipeline] sh echo upload_id : null upload_id : null [Pipeline] }