# How can I define/use a powershell command result in Jenkins as a Jenkins Variable?

Tags: powershell, variables, jenkins

I am trying to define the valor obtained from powershell command as a valor for one Jenkins variable that I use at the same stage(outside powershell command). I can not resolve that! Any idea to help me!

```
final NAMEUPDATE
      
steps {
  script {
    powershell '''
      $nameupdate = get-content D:\\updates\\nameupdates.txt
                 '''
             NAMEUPDATE = $nameupdate
```

Comment: Have a look into `returnStdout` parameter: `def nameUpdate = powershell returnStdout: true, script: 'get-content D:\\updates\\nameupdates.txt'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins scripted pipeline: Unable to print variables inside shell and set variable values in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449204/jenkins-scripted-pipeline-unable-to-print-variables-inside-shell-and-set-variab) --- Although linked question is about `sh` step, `powershell` step works the same.

Comment: Hello @zett42 !!! It  functioning with your suggest!!! Thank yoy very much again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
script {
  NAMEUPDATE = powershell 'get-content D:\\updates\\nameupdates.txt', returnStdout: true
}
```

The [documentation for the `powershell` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#powershell-powershell-script) says the following regarding the `returnStdout` argument:

> If [`true`], standard output from the task is returned as the step value as a `String`, rather than being printed to the build log. (Standard error, if any, will still be printed to the log.) You will often want to call `.trim()` on the result to strip off a trailing newline.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shane Bishop !!!! "returnStdout" solved my problem!!!!